# Android app unpublished but still see new downloads

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have Android app on Play Store.
Now I unpublished the app from Google Play Console -

[image]

[I am aware that app will not be available for the new users but old user can use it and can have update.]

But after unpublishing the app, I am still able to see some new user download for the same app.
As I unpublished app in May End, but there are some new download for app in June-July

[image]

Can any one confirm why there are new downloads? Any one faced same issue?

Comment: I came across the same issue too, do you know any solutions to explain the "New installs" for unpublished app?

Answer (score 0):

May be from apk download sites. ex: https://apkpure.com/

Answer (score 0):

there are two sources of new downloads:

1. the old users who installed the app in the past then uninstalled it and now they installed it again (Google Play Console will consider those `New Installs`)
2. 3rd party Apk distribution websites